# Setting empty objects in state to generate number of rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a requirement where I want to show only up to 6 rows (which have input fields) if this is the first time user is visiting this page then possibilities are that none of the fields were filled hence I will display only one row. The user has an option on clicking `Add More` button which will append one more row in the collection, how am I am achieving it? :

```
 Constructor
_________________

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        threshold: {},
        boxes    : [ { name: '' } ]
    };
}

Render function
_____________
 {Object.keys(this.state.boxes).map((i) => {
                    return (
                <Add the html here />
                    )
  })};



 Function which adds more rows on click 
 ___________
addMore() {
    if (this.state.boxes.length === 6) {
        return false;
    }
    this.setState({
        boxes: this.state.boxes.concat([ { name: '' } ])
    });
}
```

Things are working fine so far, what happens is if the user has 2 rows filled already and he fills one more row and clicks the save button then up to 5 rows are add in the collection, the following block of code is not working as it should:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    Object.keys(props.threshold).map((index, value) => {
        const box = { name: '' };
        if (props.threshold[ index ].threshold !== 0 && value < 6) {
            if (this.state.boxes.length < 6 && value > 0) {
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    boxes: [ ...prevState.boxes, box ]
                }));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use componentDidUpdate as **threshold** is a state and not a prop.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState, nextState) {
if (Object.keys(prevState.threshold).length !== Object.keys(nextState.threshold).length) {
 Object.keys(nextState.threshold).map((index, value) => {
        const box = { name: '' };
        if (props.threshold[ index ].threshold !== 0 && value < 6) {
            if (this.state.boxes.length < 6 && value > 0) {
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    boxes: [ ...prevState.boxes, box ]
                }));
            }
        }
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: doing that add more boxes anytime i fill anything even in frst box

Comment: Yeah that's because your every input field has a state and when you type the state changes. So in componenDidUpdate add a check like if (prevState.threshold !== nextState.threshold) then perform operations. i will edit my answer so you can understand properly

Comment: this works but upto an extent, now when the page loads no matter how many rows the user has already filled it only shows one, the perfect solution would be if user has already filled 3 rows then he is allowed to add 3 more on button click but those already filled rows should populate